# php + tidy -> attribute with just one quote -> unexpected result

Tags: php, html, tidy

Sample code:

```
$html = '<html><body><a href="https://google.com>google</a></body></html>';
$tidy = new tidy();
$tidy->parseString($html, array());
$tidy->cleanRepair();
var_dump($tidy->value);
```

Output:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<a href=
"https://google.com%3Egoogle%3C/a%3E%3C/body%3E%3C/html%3E"></a>
</body>
</html>
```

I expect my href attribute to be "https://www.google.com", but instead i get "https://google.com%3Egoogle%3C/a%3E%3C/body%3E%3C/html%3E".

How to fix that correctly?
Thanks.

Comment: You fed in garbage (missing a `"` at the end of the url) so tidy did its best to GUESS what you wanted. How is it supposed to know what the url terminated at `.com`, and that the rest of that "html" wasn't part of the url?

Comment: @MarcB yup, you are right... Just tested that html in firefox and chrome and result is the same.

Comment: doesn't matter what browser you use. the cleanup occurs on the server, and the SAME tidied html will be served up to everyone.

Comment: @MarcB no-no, i mean i loaded sample html page in browser ( firefox, chrome ) and the result ( garbled href ) was the same as after tidy cleanup.

Comment: exactly. the bad html is hardcoded on the server, the fixed html is generated on the server, and it's served up exactly the same to all browsers. tidy did its best to clean up, but obviously guessed wrong. tidy will always spit out a valid HTML document, even if what it does end up spitting out has very little relation to the broken stuff you fed in.